# Timer for speedometer

Tags: interrupts

A few years ago I wrote a c program for the ATMega168 to measure elapsed time between two triggers. Ostensibly to measure slot car speed and pellet speed from an air rifle. The processor ran at 20MHz and provided reasonable resolution with the sensors one foot apart. With the advent of Pi, I would now like to do the same with a faster device and obtain higher resolution.
My question is: How can I use an interrupt on one pin to start a timer (or read the current value) and an interrupt on a second pin to stop or read a value? I can figure out the I/O stuff, but how do I access the timer? Which timer for the highest resolution? I would like it to be as accurate as possible.
I am open to suggestions on which OS might be best suited for this sort of application.

Thanks for at least reading this far,
Rick

Comment: higher resolution does not automatically mean higher precision ... which Raspberry Pi are you asking about?

Comment: This will be an interesting experiment for you, but I don't think you'll get much accuracy with the RPi. Don't confuse resolution with accuracy. It would be a much better comparison between your ATmega and a Raspberry Pi **Pico**.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note you don't really need a timer. A clock is more than enough. You take a reading on start event and another on stop event. Subtraction of the two readings will give you duration.
The resolution will depend on the hardware (which Pi?), the OS, the language and the library.
According to /proc/timer_list, a RPi4 have some clocks with 1 nsec resolution.
If you use Python, you can use time.clock_gettime_ns( time.CLOCK_REALTIME)

```
import time
t0 = time.clock_gettime_ns( time.CLOCK_REALTIME)
t1 = time.clock_gettime_ns( time.CLOCK_REALTIME)
duration = t1-t0 # duration is integer with nanosecond resolution
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for to get me started. I had an uncommitted  pi zero W that I've started experimenting with.